# ColdFusion User login fails after session timeout

Tags: session, authentication, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We’ve recently moved to cf11 for a project and have hit on an unusual problem:

When a user lets their session timeout, and they try to login back in it takes two attempts for them to successfully log in.

When a user manually logs out, they have no problems logging in.

This problem didn’t happen in CF8. I’ve examined user scopes and cannot see a difference. I’ve tried adding the logout code before sign-in in the hope I can make the state the same. Neither has worked. Is this a known problem? And do you have a suggestion to what I can try?

EDIT:

I have an Application.cfc and result.cfm in the root of the project.
I have a signin/ folder for pages that are not logged in. That contains signin.cfm and onsignin.cfm that handles the authentication.
When running the code, wait for the session to time out before logging in again with the same user name again.

signin/signin.cfm

```
<form action="onsignin.cfm" method="POST" >
    User name: <input name="login" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="btnSubmit" >
</form>
```

signin/onsignin.cfm

```
<cffunction name="authenticate" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="login" />
    <cflogin idletimeout="3600">
        <cfloginuser name="#arguments.login#" password="1234AbCd" roles="admin,developer,login_session,login_signoff" />
    </cflogin>
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>

<cfscript>
    authenticate(trim(Login));
    writeOutput("At /signin/onsignin.cfm<br/>");
    writeOutput("IsUserLoggedIn: #IsUserLoggedIn()#<br /><hr/>");
</cfscript>

<cflocation url="../result.cfm" addToken="no" /><!--- before we get to result.cfm onRequestStart() in Application.cfc is triggered. --->
```

Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset THIS.Name = "LoginTest" />
    <cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
    <cfset THIS.ClientManagement = false />
    <cfset THIS.LoginStorage = "session" />
    <cfset THIS.setClientCookies = false />
    <cfset This.sessiontimeout= createTimeSpan(0,0,0,20)/><!--- 20second timeout to show the session problem --->

    <cffunction name="outputCurrentLoginState" access="private">
        <cfargument name="currentFunction" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfscript>
            writeOutput("In function: #arguments.currentFunction# state is <br />");
            writeOutput("TargetPage: #arguments.TargetPage# <br />");
            writeOutput("GetAuthUser: #GetAuthUser()#<br />");
            writeOutput("GetUserRoles: #GetUserRoles()#<br />");
            writedump(session);
            writedump(cookie);
            writeOutput("IsUserLoggedIn: #IsUserLoggedIn()#<br /><hr />");
            /*use writeLog() to view to Console */
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="OnRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean">
        <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfset outputCurrentLoginState("OnRequestStart",arguments.TargetPage)/>
        <cfif not IsDefined("Cookie.CFID")>
            <CFLOCK SCOPE="SESSION" TYPE="exclusive" TIMEOUT="5">
                <cfcookie name="CFID" value="#SESSION.CFID#" secure="false" httpOnly="true" />
                <cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="#SESSION.CFTOKEN#" secure="false" httpOnly="true" />
            </CFLOCK>
        </cfif>
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="OnRequest" access="public">
        <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfset outputCurrentLoginState("OnRequest",arguments.TargetPage)/>
        <cfif findNoCase("signin/", arguments.TargetPage)>
            <cflogout/>
        </cfif>
        <cfinclude template="#ARGUMENTS.TargetPage#" />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

result.cfm

```
<cfscript>
    writeOutput("GetAuthUser: #GetAuthUser()#<br />");
    writeOutput("GetUserRoles: #GetUserRoles()#<br />");
    writeOutput("--- IsUserLoggedIn: #IsUserLoggedIn()#<br />");
    writeOutput("At /result.cfm<hr/>");
</cfscript>
```

Update: Now I have the test code above that fails for cf11, I tried it on a cf8 server and in cf8 it works as I expect it to. When the session times out, the user does not have any problem creating a new session. It is only in cf11 were it fails.

Comment: No, it's not a known problem I'm afraid. What you need to do is give us some code to look at. Not your actual application, but a minimal case that demonstrates the issue (see http://sscce.org/). There is not enough to go on with the info you've thusfar provided.

Comment: Pure shot in the dark, but is it possible that when user session is timed out and user is taken to login screen, you have cfid and cftoken as part of url? That may cause to ignite the older session. As @AdamCameron said, without seeing any code, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You’re right – I should have supplied code. I have tried removing the application code, but unfortunately and predictably the problem goes away. I've edited the issue to give a bit more detail.

Comment: If you removed the application code and the problem went away it is obviously an issue with your code. Right? So start putting the application code back in, piece by piece, until it breaks again. That will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Yes - I had a difficult job stripping the code to the bones to clearly show the problem. I’ve managed that now. (Sorry for the delay.)

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with the new attribute `allowconcurrent` that was added in ColdFusion 11 and by default is set to `true`. Try setting that attribute to false `<cflogin idletimeout="3600" allowconcurrent="false">` in order to make the `cflogin` tag work like it used to in ColdFusion 8. I think the real root of the problem is that you have a shorter session timeout (20 seconds here) than the `cflogin` tags `idletimeout` (3600 seconds here). As you have `loginStorage` set to `session` the `cflogin` tag is attempting to keep the user in but the session is being torn down.

Comment: Thank you Miguel – I had 20seconds here in the test code so it would be easy to recreate the error. In production it is much longer. I have tried changing `idletimeout`, to be less or to match the `sessiontimeout` but that didn’t affect the outcome and the bug was the same.
However, changing `allowconcurrent` to `false` does change the result. Thank you for spotting that. Changing `allowconcurrent` isn’t going to be an acceptable solution for my application. This looks like an undocumented **bug in cf11**.

Comment: I posted an answer for other users to find easier. Please see my response there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a work around that will be good enough for my use case.
Old code:

```
<cflogin idletimeout="3600">
<cfloginuser name="#yourlogin#" password="#yourpassword#" roles="#yourroles#" />
</cflogin>
```

New code:

```
<cflogin idletimeout="3600" allowconcurrent="false">
<cfloginuser name="#yourlogin##createUUID()#" password="#yourpassword#" roles="#yourroles#" />
</cflogin>
```

Adding a random value to the `cfloginuser name` attribute should make everyone unique, even if they use the same credentials when you validate them against a database.
It’s a bit of a hack, but it gets around the issue.
Thank you for everyone’s help… Especially **Miguel** for picking up on `allowconcurrent`.

Answer (score 2):

I've added the following comment on [3839458](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3839458):

---

Another workaround is duplicate the cflogin. Example:

```
<cflogin ..>
<cflogin ..>
```

When both have allowconcurrent=true (the default), then both will run. isUserLoggedIn() returns YES after the 1st, but the 1st login actually fails. The 2nd runs and logs in correctly.

Repro attached as Application.cfc

When THIS.loginStorage="cookie", then the issue does not reoccur if an old cfauthorization cookie is still present.

---

Thanks!,

-Aaron

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

There is already a bug opened with Adobe about this issue - [Bug 3839458](http://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3839458). I suggest you add your experience and vote on that bug. It currently has a status of "ToTrack" with a reason of "PRNeedInfo". I have voted for it as well and added a reference to this question for more info.

---

*Promoted from the comments*

I think the problem is that you have set the `idletimeout` attribute of the `<cflogin>` tag to a value (3600 seconds) which is longer than your session timeout value (20 seconds). That is not a valid approach. I realize that you have set the session timeout at 20 seconds for ease of testing. However, it does not make sense to have a longer `idletimeout` than session timeout when you are setting your `loginStorage` to be `session`. The `<cflogin>` tag is attempting to keep the user's session active but the session itself is being torn down outside of it's control. That is asking for trouble in my opinion. Keep the `idletimeout` setting less than or at least equal to the session timeout setting.

I suspect the difference you are seeing between ColdFusion versions might have to do with a new attribute that was added to the `<cflogin>` tag in ColdFusion 11. The `allowconcurrent` attribute ([documentation reference](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflogin)). By default that setting is set to `true` meaning concurrent login sessions should be allowed. Try setting that attribute to false, as in, `<cflogin idletimeout="3600" allowconcurrent="false">`. I believe that will make the `<cflogin>` tag work like it used to in ColdFusion 8.

You mention in the comments that setting `allowconcurrent` to `false` is not an acceptable solution. Why? That is how it is working for you on ColdFusion 8. I feel that the behavior you are seeing is "working as designed". However, if you feel that this is a bug then [please enter a bug for it with Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/).

As an aside, I also noticed that you are setting `ClientManagement` and `setClientCookies` both to `false`. Yet in your `OnRequestStart` method you are setting those cookies. Why? They are not needed for session management. The ColdFusion server will handle that for you.

Comment: Hi Miguel -- `allowconcurrent` to `false` isn’t suitable for us because this isn’t how it works in CF8. In CF8 you can login multiple times and it doesn’t have this login issue – that’s why  `allowconcurrent  = "true"` is the default  in CF11. Therefore I don’t think it can’t be claimed to be working as designed. By the way, I’m manually setting the cookies because I want to override the default settings. If you remove the cfcookie code, the error will be the same.

Comment: And apparently there has been a bug opened about it - https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3839458  I suggest you add your experience and vote on that bug. It currently has a status of "ToTrack" with a reason of "PRNeedInfo".